# Will smoothing splines always lead to continuous $\hat{f}$?

Tags: statistics, spline

I found these notes referencing smoothing splines in elements of mathematical learning. I'm just confused why (3) is False because I really can't think of a counter example

1. λ can be chosen by cross-validation : **True**
2. If λ = 0 and $x_i$ are different, smoothing splines will lead to a training error of zero: **True**
3. Smoothing splines will always lead to continuous $\hat{f}$ : **False**
4. Larger λ correspond to less flexible models:  **True**

Definition:

[image: Def:]

Comment: "Smoothing spline" refers to a broad family of estimators that vary in different aspects, one of which being the choice of smoothing penalty. Can you provide the definition being considered in the context of your notes?

Comment: @angryavian I have edited my post

Comment: Based on the provided definition, $\hat{f}$ must belong to $C^2$ by definition, so it is not only continuous but it is twice continuously differentiable.